# Installed wifi-ap snap on Core 18 and immediately lost connection

Tags: ubuntu-core

I installed wifi-ap snap on Core 18 and immediately lost connection. How can I reconnect via ssh? I am hesitant to unplug for fear of corruption.

```
Please see 'snap --help' for app installation and updates.
Last login: Thu Jan 14 21:03:21 2021 from 192.168.1.14
jaalfs@linux:~$ snap install wifi-ap
wifi-ap 30 from Canonical✓ installed
jaalfs@linux:~$ Connection reset by 192.168.1.34 port 22

C:\Users\jaalfs>ssh jaalfs@192.168.1.34
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.34 port 22: Connection timed out

C:\Users\jaalfs>ssh jaalfs@192.168.1.34
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.34 port 22: Connection timed out

C:\Users\jaalfs>ssh jaalfs@192.168.1.34
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.34 port 22: Connection timed out
```

*** Update ***
It appears wifi-ap started automatically after install. I can see a wifi AP with SSID Ubuntu from my cell phone. However, I cannot connect to Ubuntu because a random password was automatically assigned.

Comment: if your system is only connected over wifi you can't have the wifi ap online at the same time as your wifi connection to the Network.  You'd have to access the system directly and remove wifi-ap

Comment: That makes sense. Since it is a core install the only access is via SSH. Any ideas on how to access the system.

Comment: I am assuming you do not have access to the device physically or via console.  If that is the case then you're SOL - your only recourse would be to reinstall the system.

Comment: I have access physically, but core is supposed to be ultra secure. Maybe an ethernet connection to the board will allow me to SSH into it.

Comment: This seems like a huge flaw in the wifi-ap snap. How could I have installed it and configured it?

Comment: Had to reinstall. Be aware of installing wifi-ap snap on Core (not Core Snap on desktop/server) because wifi-ap has an auto wizard that makes the snap connections, spins up the access-point with SSID: Ubuntu and a secure RANDOM password. On Core this is a deathwish because you immediately loose your SSH connection and then there is no way to log back in.